# variable accesible in php class built in the construtor that references another class?

Tags: php, class, scope

So, in short I'd like my login class to not have to create a new instance of my DB class within in function. Currently I'm trying to do it like this:

```
<?php

class siteLogin
{

private $db;
private $dataStore;

function __construct()
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }

    require_once '../application/db.php';
    $this->$db = new DB();
    require_once '../application/data.php';
    $this->$dataStore = new Data($db);
}
```

But I get the error:

```
 Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\var\www\sexdiaries.co.uk\class\siteLoginClass.php on line 16
```

I would like to give give `$this->$db` the reference to `siteLogin` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the right notation for properties. Try this instead:

```
$this->db = new DB();
$this->dataStore = new Data($db);
```

They aren't prefixed with `$` like normal variables. This is because you can use variable property names in PHP, e.g.

```
$foo = 'db';
echo $this->$foo; // equivalent to `echo $this->db;`
```

In your case, `$db` was an undefined variable that got initialised to an empty string (although a PHP notice would have been triggered - do you have error reporting on?), so you were effectively trying to access a property of the same name, hence the error `Cannot access empty property`.